# Calling other xll files from C#/ExcelDNA code

Tags: c#, excel, plugins, xll, excel-dna

I have some ExcelDNA C# code which I am working on, and within Excel an xll plugin that I'd like to be able to access.  I am not able to get the source code of this plugin - it has to be used as is.  So is there a method of being able to access these functions from C#?

Comment: And could someone with a high enough reputation add an ExcelDNA tag please?!  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for adding the excel-dna tag!

Comment: No problem. I just got my shiny new tag-creating powers. I also want to learn more about ExcelDNA, since I'm thinking of using it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great to see an ExcelDna tag on StackOverflow!

You should take a look at making a call to xlUDF. It should allow you make a call to any UDF (including that of your XLL so long as it's loaded).

The MSDN description is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687892.aspx), with a similar question answered on [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_thread/thread/44a05c258f5a7780?pli=1).

I hope this helps - please let me know how you get on as I would like to add xlUDF to my list of ExcelDna [examples](http://www.technicana.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=92).

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can use GET.PROCEDURES from http://xllutility.codeplex.com to get a list of all loaded add-ins and their C signature from the third column of the array this returns.

This is a more general answer on how to call functions in any xll from any language that can call C. If you are using ExcelDna then the xlUDF route is much simpler.